# Jetpack Compose - How do I make an image the size of the largest other element in a layout?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

On my Android App, I want to make a composable that has a TextField surounded by increment buttons (-/+) in a Row

[image: TextField with increment buttons (wanted result)]

I want my buttons (I used Image composables to remove the unwanted padding) to be the height of my TextField and a fixed width. The problem is that I can't find a way to do this, Intrinsic size will take the images' size.

Here's the code :

```
@Composable
fun TextFieldWithIncrements(
    value: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Row(
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.arrow_left),
            colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(Color.Red),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(50.dp)
                .padding(end = 4.dp)
                .border(
                    1.dp,
                    Color.Red,
                    RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)
                )
                .clickable(
                    interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                    indication = rememberRipple(
                        bounded = true,
                        color = Color.Red
                    ),
                    onClick = { },
                )
                .padding(4.dp)
        )
        Box(
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
        ) {
            BasicTextField(
                value = value,
                onValueChange = {  },
                textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge.copy(
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                ),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(75.dp)
                    .padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
                    .border(
                        1.dp,
                        Color.Gray,
                        RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)
                    )
                    .padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
            )
        }
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.arrow_right),
            colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(Color.Green),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(50.dp)
                .padding(start = 4.dp)
                .border(
                    1.dp,
                    Color.Green,
                    RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)
                )
                .clickable(
                    interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                    indication = rememberRipple(
                        bounded = true,
                        color = Color.Green
                    ),
                    onClick = { },
                )
                .padding(4.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

And here's what I get :

[image: TextField with increment buttons (actual result)]

Comment: You can try setting your Image Size As ```IntristicSize.Min```. it should work

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following things

- You can give `modifier = modifier.height(Intrinsic.MIN)` on your Row composable, after this it should take minimum height out of all composables,
- You have to specify some height to the `Textboxfield Box`
- Now you can do `Modifier.fillMaxHeight()` to both the image composable.
- If you are using weight then it helps only when all the other composables in the row have weight specified in modifier.

I hope it will work, Thanks

Comment: I already tried `IntrinsicSize.Min` and with no height specified for the Images or `fillMaxHeight()` but the images get their height based on their ration and width (and end up bigger than the TextField). I also don't want to specify a height on my TextField because it wouldn't be very responsive I want everything to depend on the textField font size. And the weight is only here so that if the composable is stretch, my buttons stay on the sides and the textfield stays in the middle.

Comment: I know I could use a constraint layout but it complicates things so i'm trying to see if it's possible with a simple row

Comment: I guess the bigger question is : In general, is it possible to make a row's height, the height of a specific item inside and have the others' height "match parent"? It was really easy on XML so feel like there should be an easy way to do it in Compose

Comment: Actually it is not possible for a composable to have a height greater than its parent, 
I'll surely look into that in a while, it made me curious too!

Answer (score 0):

You can get `TextField` height with `onSizeChanged` modifier and set images' heights to it.

At the top of `TextFieldWithIncrements`

```
var rowH by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }
val density = LocalDensity.current
fun Int.asDp() = density.run {
    this@asDp.toDp()
}
```

`BasicTextField` modifier

```
.onSizeChanged {
    rowH = it.height.asDp()
}
```

`Image` modifier

```
.height(rowH)
```

Comment: When I tried it, it only worked when I made the default state higher than the final height. So it only works to reduce the height, meaning that if I stack multiple of these it can cause problems.

Comment: I don't understand, what default state and final height? I tested it and it does make buttons the same height as `TextField`, no matter if they were smaller or bigger initially. @Damon

Comment: Oh ! You're right, it was because of the box, I had to make the box's height Intinsic. I was hoping for a cleaner way but that works. Thanks